# calculating the value of 1 column based on conditions on other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to calculate the value of a given column based on a condition.

The base dataframe looks like this (assuming that cols a and b are coming from a previous manipulation, hence the insertion):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5],'b':[6,7,8,9,10]})

df.insert(1, 'calculated', np.nan)
```

Now, I'm trying to calculate the value of 'calculated' based on 'a' and 'b'.

I tried iterating over the dataframe rows, but the 'calculated' column does not get calculated...

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['a']>2:
        row['calculated'] = row['b']*2
    else:
        row['calculated'] = row['b']
```

[image: result of iterrows]

- Using `df.apply` does not seem to do the trick because all examples I found where using lambdas (how do you pass values of a and return data to calculated with a lambda?)

I managed to do it with the following code:

```
df.loc[df['a'] > 2, 'calculated'] = df['b']*2
df.loc[df['a'] <= 2, 'calculated'] = df['b']
```

However, this code is quite 'error prone' and is kind of hard to read.

Is there a 'lot cleaner' way to achieve this? A way to add logic easily.

something like?

```
def get_calculated_value(row):
  if row['a'] > 2:
    row['calculated'] = row['b'] * 2
  else:
    row['calculated'] = row['a']

df.apply(get_calculated_value())
```

Comment: `df['calculated'] = df['b'].mul(df['a'].gt(2).add(1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use apply function with lambda. You don't need to assign 'calculated' column inside the function. Also, using apply(), you can add or modify conditions later on.

```
def myfunc(row):
    if row['a'] > 2:
        return row['b'] * 2
    else:
        return row['a']

df['calculated'] = df.apply(lambda x : myfunc(x), axis=1)

#output
df

    a   b   calculated
0   1   6   1
1   2   7   2
2   3   8   16
3   4   9   18
4   5   10  20
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5],'b':[6,7,8,9,10]})

df['calculated'] = df["b"].where(df["b"]>2, df["b"]*2)
display(df)
```

Comment: even though your solution is technically right, I prefer the one from @vbrises because: your solution's syntax remains cryptic (while being shorter), it mixes syntaxes (df['a'] vs df.a) and vbrises' solution allows to add a lot more logic to the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

There is a much faster way to do it using [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

`df['calculated']=np.where(df.a>2,2*df.b,df.b)`